# Holomorphic non constant function on and inside of the unit circle, satisfies $|f(z)|=1$ on unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a non constant holomorphic function on and inside of the unit circle $C:=\{z\in \mathbb C~:~|z|=1\}$. Suppose $|f(z)|=1$ on $C$, then for $D=\{z\in \mathbb C~:~|z|\leq 1\}$, prove that $f: \bar{D}\rightarrow \bar{D}$ is onto.

Since $f$ is non constant, maximum modulus gives that $|f(z)| <1$ on $D$. But it is not enough to say that $f$ is onto.

Comment: Hint: use rouche theorem on $f(z)-z_0, z-z_0$ for all $z_0\in \mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ has at least one zero: this follows applying Rouche's theorem to $f(z);f(z)-f(z_0)$, where $z_0\in \mathbb{D}$ is such that :$f(z_0)\neq 0$. Indeed, on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ we have
 $$1=|f(z)|>|f(z_0)|=|f(z)-(f(z)-f(z_0))|$$

Since $f(z)-f(z_0)$ has at least one zero (in $z_0$), by R.T. $f$ has at least one zero.

For every $w:|w|<1$, $f(z)-w$ has at least one zero, as you can prove applying Rouche's theorem to $f(z);f(z)-w$. Indeed, on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ we have

$$1=|f(z)|>|w|=|f(z)-(f(z)-w)|$$

Since $f$ has at least one zero, $f-w$ has at least one zero, i.e. $f^{-1}(w)\neq \emptyset$

Now, for the last part, we need to prove that $f(\partial \mathbb{D})=\partial \mathbb{D}$. Let $z_n$ be a sequence of points in the interior of the unit disc converging to a general point $z\in \partial \mathbb{D}$, and let $w_n:w_n\in f^{-1}(z_n)\in \mathbb{D}$. Since the closed unit disc is compact, we can extract a convergent subsequence $\hat{w}_n\to w\in \partial \mathbb{D}$. By continuity $f(w)=z$. Since $z$ was general we have proven the assertion

Answer (score 0):

$f$ has finitely many zeroes in $\mathbb D$ (why?); number them $a_1,...a_n$ repeating them if of higher multiplicities and take the finite Blaschke product $B(z)=\Pi_{k=1}^n \frac{z-a_k}{1-\bar a_k z}, B(z)=1$ if no zeroes.

Then $g=f/B$ is analytic satisfies the same properties as $f$ (why?) but has no zeroes inside the unit disc, so $\frac{1}{g}$ satisfies same properties so both $|g| \le 1, |\frac {1}{g}| \le 1$ on the unit disc, hence $g=\alpha,|\alpha|=1$, hence $f=\alpha B$. Since $f$ nonconstant, $n \ge 1$ so $f$ is a nonconstant rational function of a special type.

Now show that $B$ is a $n:1$ map of the unit disc to itself (hint: argument principle or fundamental theorem of algebra plus $B(\mathbb D) \subset \mathbb D, B(\mathbb D_e) \subset \mathbb D_e$, whhere $\mathbb D_e$ is the exterior of the closed unit disc)